# Normal Windows XP on a tablet (HP tx2009)

Tags: windows-xp, tablet

My tablet HP tx2009 came with Vista pre-installed. However, since my organization had some Windows XP licenses lying unused, I thought of installing one on my tablet. After that, I also installed the Service Pack 3.

It is running great. Photoshop CS3 runs faster on larger images. However I am facing certain issues. Can anyone suggest any pointers as to how to resolve these?

1. Whenever the monitor goes off (Power settings) or I switch it off using some laptop screen switching utility (such as Wizmo), I cannot get it back on, without pressing Fn + F4 (that is the shortcut used to change primary monitor in case I attach an external monitor)
2. Hibernate does not work. It used to for a day or two, but now has stopped.
3. Standby doesn't work.

If I can get these things to work properly, I would be happy with XP; otherwise I would have to re-install Vista or upgrade to 7.

Comment: You have better user experience with tablet, when you install Windows 7. I recommending upgrade to Win7

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 is an option as MicTech suggested, but if you want to stick with XP then from the sounds of things it is drivers that your tablet is either missing in need of updating. Try going to the manufacturers website and downloading the most up to date drivers for your platform.

Comment: Actually, since my tablet didn't come with XP drivers, so I had to go to manufacturer's website to download them. I guess they are the latest ones. So I think I will have to upgrade to Windows 7. Thanks for responses.

Comment: Not always, some manufacturers are very lazy about updating their drivers once the machine ships. Find out the hardware and go directly to the device manufacturers website.